# What type of view is the Twitter profile on iOS? UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, twitter

Is the twitter profile view in iOS just ONE very dynamic table view? What's in the header and what's in the cells? I've just started developing for iOS and I'm trying to look at the big players and identify what they use and how they use it.
I've made a similar view, but it's a view comprised of carefully placed subviews, and I'm wondering if something like this would be a better route.

If it is a UITableView, how do they have such dynamic cells with different spacing between them etc? I know you can vary cell sizes, layouts, and insets, but to this degree, in one tableview?

Please don't jump me with downvotes for asking a non-technical question only twitter devs know for sure, I'm just really curious and don't know where else to ask. I'm only looking for a professional opinion.

[image: Profile top]

[image: Profile scrolled down]

Comment: Rather than jumping you for asking a non-technical question, people are probably going to jump you for asking a question that only Twitter's devs can answer for certain.

Comment: I'm aware that only Twitter devs know the true inner working of their app, but I'm sure there is a professional out there who could give a fairly valid answer with justification.

Comment: You should have a look at this app http://revealapp.com I think you should be able to see whats going on under the views of most apps.

Comment: and have a look at this open source project which mimics the stretchy pull down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it could be a very dynamic UITableView to me. Or at least, it could probably be recreated as a UITableView if it isn't already.

I'm looking at a twitter profile page now, and I would say there's probably 5 sections:

1. Header (everything from the profile picture to the "follow" button)
2. Recent Tweets (including the "view more" button)
3. Photos
4. "Special" items (Following, Followers, Favorites and Lists)
5. Who to Follow

The only component of this view that strikes me as particularly unique and special is the banner image that blurs and zooms when you pull down too far. I'm not quite sure how they pulled that off. It's possible that they track the offset of the scroll view, and if the offset is positive (i.e. it was pulled down), then zoom and blur the banner (and use the offset value as a scaling factor somehow).

All the other components could be probably be recreated by (carefully) designing custom UITableViewCells for each unique purpose (e.g. tweets, image carousel, other profiles), and then populating those cells with data from the tweet or profile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The "drag down the picture to zoom and blur" effect is also used in Tinder - I suppose it's starting to gain popularity.